# Working with Query Table in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I am getting a "Subscript out of Range" Error 9 with my code. I have a Microsoft Access database connected to Excel and a table already made with the Query for Table "QUERY_1". I want to update the table with "QUERY_2" through using VBA. The error occurs on this line:

```
Set QueryARV = QuerySheet.QueryTables(1)
```

Here is the full procedure:

```
Sub ChooseQueryTable()

Dim QueryARV As QueryTable
Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet

Set QuerySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set QueryARV = QuerySheet.QueryTables(1)

With QueryARV
.CommandType = xlCmdTable
.CommandText = "QUERY_1"
.Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `MsgBox QuerySheet.QueryTables.Count` show you?

Comment: Giving me back a 0. I have tried using QueryTables("Table Name"), but no success with that either.

Comment: I may be calling a Query Table incorrectly? I connected Access and Excel and in the Command Text have a table named "QUERY_1". I want to be able to change that name to "QUERY_2". Is that not done through using the QueryTable function?

Comment: "subscipt out of range" from `QuerySheet.QueryTables(1)` made me suspect `QuerySheet.QueryTables.Count` is zero.  But I've never actually used QueryTables, so can't suggest how to fix it.

Comment: I think I have found a solution by using Querysheet.ListObject.Item(1).QueryTable. I am unsure why it needs to be called a List Object item first, but I also do not have much expereince with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In a newly created MS Excel Workbook by default you have only 3 Worksheets, so pertinent to your case, either change the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")` , or add another Worksheet to make sure that `Sheet4` actually exists - issue resolved*

I would also recommend to modify your code by adding proper error handling as shown below:

```
Sub ChooseQueryTable()
    Dim QueryARVIS As QueryTable
    Dim QuerySheet As Worksheet
On Error GoTo err:
    Set QuerySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If (QuerySheet.QueryTables.Count > 0) Then
        Set QueryARVIS = QuerySheet.QueryTables(1)
        With QueryARVIS
            .CommandType = xlCmdTable
            .CommandText = "10K_WELLCOUNT_PERMIAN_ID"
            .Refresh
        End With
    End If
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox (err.Description)
End Sub
```

Please make sure that `QuerySheet.QueryTables(1)` actually exists (most likely it doesn't). Hope this will help. Best regards

Comment: I should specify, I do have 3 other Sheets in this Workbook. I have edited the post to say "Sheet1" for simplicity however.